# An algorithm for reconstructing a graph from its shortest path information?

Tags: algorithms

I have some shortest path data for a graph. Can I reconstruct the graph itself from this data?

More precisely, I have a boolean (0/1) matrix for each vertex *v* in graph *(V, E)*. Matrix element *[s,d]* is equal to 1 iff *v* is in the shortest path from source vertex *s* to destination vertex *d*. All edges in the graph have the same length.

For example, for the graph

```
(V1) -- (V2) -- (V3)
```

the three matrices would be:

V1:

```
1 1 1
1 0 0
1 0 0
```

V2:

```
0 1 1
1 1 1
1 1 0
```

V3:

```
0 0 1
0 0 1
1 1 1
```

My questions:

1) is there an algorithm to reconstruct the set of edges E from these matrices?

2) is solution always unique? (this is more of a personal curiosity than a real requirement)

3) can the algorithm be generalized to nonuniform edge lengths?

Comment: If there is an edge between two vertices `v1` and `v2`, then exactly these two vertices are in the shortest path between `v1` and `v2`. So for any other vertex `v`, `[v1, v] == 0 == [v, v1]` in the matrix of `v2`, and `[v2, v] == 0 == [v, v2]` in the matrix of `v1`.

Comment: Maybe I am wrong, but arent 1) and 2) equivalent?

Comment: I am not sure if 1) and 2) are equivalent: there might be more than one graph for a given shortest path information and also an algorithm that finds all possible solutions.

Comment: Ok, but that's a different problem. The point was to *reconstruct* a graph from the set of these matrices, not to compute whether there is a solution which would satisfy the constrains encoded in these matrices.

Comment: See my first comment, if the statement it contains is correct, it gives an algorithm for reconstructing the graph.

Comment: @Giorgio: thanks, I see how to write a simple O(n^3) algorithm now.

Comment: I think the algorithm cannot be generalized to the case of nonuniform edge lengths but I haven't proved it.

Comment: @Giorgio adding a single edge from v1 to v3 that is longer than v1-v2-v3 results in the same set of matrices unless I'm missing something - so would be a counterexample for the non-uniform edge case

Comment: @kfx in your O(n^3) algorithm, what is n? |V|? |E|? The runtime complexity of most graph algos in my experience are expressed like O(|V|+|E|), for example.

Comment: @durron597: in my comment, n=|V|. The actual size of the input is |V|^3.

Answer (score 2):

you can extract the adjacency matrix by from the path matrices by using the following property.

There is a edge between 2 vertexes `s` and `d` *if and only if* the shortest path between them contains only `s` and `d`.

For non-uniform length you will only get the unique solution if the [triangle inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_inequality) holds. Otherwise a graph with `d(p1,p2)=1` `d(p2,p3)=2` and `d(p1,p3)=4` will show the shortest path between `p1` and `p3` as through `p2` instead of the direct connection. Which means that the edge [p1,p3] will never be part of any shortest path.